# RESTful api - cross domain put request issue

Tags: php, rest, request, cross-domain, put

I'm a long time overflower and eventually signed up.
I've gone through tons of threads but none could help me with my problem.
I am about to create a RESTful API with the slim framework in php and have problems with the crossdomain put requests.

Let me give you a quick introduction to what I've done.
After wrtining the first GET requests I was looking for a method to test my API easily and found the "RESTClient" Firefox addon, it worked well so I continued using it.
After a few tests I tested a self-written code on another server and there the problem occured.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at %1$S. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).

What I wonder the most about is the fact that **the Firefox addon had no problem to make the request at any time, it always showed the expected response**. The error above just occured when I tried to send a request by my own code. I read a lot about cross-origin requests but nothing helped me, I hope you can.

Now first of all let me show you my slim framework php code

```
<?php
header('access-control-allow-origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

function output($arr){
    echo json_encode($arr);
    exit;
}

require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->put(
    '/put',
    function () {
        $output = array("status"=>"200","message"=>"This is a put test");
        output($output);
    }
);

$app->run();
?>
```

And my test.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            (function($) {
                    var url = 'URL';

                    $.ajax({
                    type: 'put',
                    url: url,
                    async: false,
                    crossDomain:true,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(json) {
                       console.log(json);
                    },
                    error: function(e) {
                       console.log(e.message);
                    }
                });

            })(jQuery);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can someone please explain to me how I can get this PUT request working. I am really in this despair mood right now. I understand all that cross-domain topic but why is he not letting it go after i set the access-control-allow-origin in the php code ? What is the firefox addon doing different? ...

Comment: The Firefox extension does not have to follow the Same Origin Policy, any javascript that gets run on the page does. The problem might be due to setting `async: false`, try setting that to `true` and see what happens.

Comment: thanks for your help but that does not fix it, same error as before

Comment: try putting following code in ajax.... contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you forget to add methods in the header.[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164362/cross-domain-rest-api-post-put-get-delete)

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
```